# Does dotnetnuke 9 supports Arabic languages?

Tags: dotnetnuke-9, dotnetnuke

I want to user Arabic language in [`dotnetnuke`](http://www.dnnsoftware.com).

I am using `dotnetnuke` version 9.

Does `dotnetnuke` 9 support Arabic languages?

Comment: You should use `Resource (.resx)` files, DNN doesn't translate anything for you.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer appears to be:

> you should localize your portal; and for create right to left portal you should edit Default.css file in 'portals/_default' directory
>
> Regards
>
> Mohammad

[Reference](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/arabic-mode)